# Python 2.7 division not showing exact result

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I divide 1/5e-5 it gives the correct answer but 1/5e-6 gives an answer close to the correct one.

```
>>> 1/5e-5
20000.0
>>> 1/5e-6
199999.99999999997 (should be 200000)
>>>
```

How can I get it to show the exact value. I tried importing decimel, numpy and scipy but none of them change the result.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.1/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: You should read up on [floating point rounding error](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/101163/what-causes-floating-point-rounding-errors). The basic issue is that computers cannot exactly model certain decimal fractions in binary, much like we cannot model 2/3 (0.66667...) in decimal.

Comment: You can't always get an "exact value" with floating-point math.

Comment: Could you make use of the [fractions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html) module?

Comment: To get python to round the number to some level of precision, try [round(1/5e-6)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round)

Comment: I'm not sure that this is an exact dupe -- OP seems to be at least a little aware of the limitations of floating point mathematics (based on the attempts to use `decimal`, `scipy`, `numpy`, ...).  The question is if there is any way to work-around the limitations of floating point math to get an exact answer.  It seems to me that it should be possible with decimal or fractions . . .

Comment: @NickWhite rounding doesn't help, because most perfectly exact decimals simply can't be represented in binary. You can round it 100 times but you still get the same almost-but-not-quite answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get `decimal` to do this properly -- You just have to avoid using floating point numbers along the way:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.Decimal('1') / (decimal.Decimal('5') / decimal.Decimal('1000000'))
Decimal('2E+5')
```

Comment: You can use floating point numbers converted to `Decimal`, as long as they're exact. Integers converted to floating point will meet this requirement as long as they're less than `2**53`.